# Building up a dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I am trying to build a dataframe of 10k records to then save to a parquet file on Spark 2.4.3 standalone
The following works in a small scale up to 1000 records but takes forever when ramping up to 10k

```
scala> import spark.implicits._
import spark.implicits._

scala> var someDF = Seq((0, "item0")).toDF("x", "y")
someDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [x: int, y: string]

scala> for ( i <- 1 to 1000 ) {someDF = someDF.union(Seq((i,"item"+i)).toDF("x", "y")) }

scala>   someDF.show
+---+------+
|  x|     y|
+---+------+
|  0| item0|
|  1| item1|
|  2| item2|
|  3| item3|
|  4| item4|
|  5| item5|
|  6| item6|
|  7| item7|
|  8| item8|
|  9| item9|
| 10|item10|
| 11|item11|
| 12|item12|
| 13|item13|
| 14|item14|
| 15|item15|
| 16|item16|
| 17|item17|
| 18|item18|
| 19|item19|
+---+------+
only showing top 20 rows


[Stage 2:=========================================================(20 + 0) / 20]

scala> var someDF = Seq((0, "item0")).toDF("x", "y")
someDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [x: int, y: string]

scala>   someDF.show
+---+-----+
|  x|    y|
+---+-----+
|  0|item0|
+---+-----+


scala> for ( i <- 1 to 10000 ) {someDF = someDF.union(Seq((i,"item"+i)).toDF("x", "y")) }
```

Just want to save `someDF` to a parquet file to then load into Impala

Comment: Union is a heavy distributed operation. And you are applying it 10K times. Instead, create an ordinary scala list of 10K documents and then call `Seq(my_list).toDF("x", "y")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//declare Range that you want
scala> val r = 1 to 10000

//create DataFrame with range 
scala> val df  = sc.parallelize(r).toDF("x")

//Add new column "y"
scala> val final_df = df.select(col("x"),concat(lit("item"),col("x")).alias("y"))
scala> final_df.show

+---+------+
|  x|     y|
+---+------+
|  1| item1|
|  2| item2|
|  3| item3|
|  4| item4|
|  5| item5|
|  6| item6|
|  7| item7|
|  8| item8|
|  9| item9|
| 10|item10|
| 11|item11|
| 12|item12|
| 13|item13|
| 14|item14|
| 15|item15|
| 16|item16|
| 17|item17|
| 18|item18|
| 19|item19|
| 20|item20|
+---+------+

scala> final_df.count
res17: Long = 10000

//Write final_df to path in parquet format
scala> final_df.write.format("parquet").save(<path to write>)
```

Comment: @Jose Martinez Poblete, I have taken range from 1 to 10000, You can take it from 0 for your exact answer.----

Comment: GRACIAS!  So my loop took some 15 minutes (forever) 
But spark-shell did not crash!
It was then when I tried to show when it crashed 
However, your commands worked like a charm!